# Pass text past / in URL into new URL, with the text past / (IIS)

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to make it so if I try to access `mysite.com/styles.css`, IIS will URL-Rewrite me to `example.com/load.php/?url=/styles.css`

However, `mysite.com/styles.css` will almost never be the same.  That's purely an example.  It could be `myblog.biz/somemindblownpost` but still needs to redirect in the same way.  I have no way to predict what will be thrown at it.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want literally every url that that is not `load.php` to be thrown at `/load.php?...`?

Comment: @cfqueryparam Yes...

Answer (score 0):

this post will help you 
[http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module][1]

[1]: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module you just need to use the IIS URL rewrite as it mention in the post

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work...  Erm...  I know literally nothing about the syntax of URL-Rewriting.  Also, this doesn't indicate a way to have a dynamic original URL.  `styles.css` may sometimes not be `styles.css`, and could be `somepage.html`.  Sorry, I didn't make this clear in the post.  I've edited it.